# To catch the plate for a strike (baseball)

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What is the general meaning of this sentence?

> I believe I caught the corner of the plate for a strike.

Full text:

*although I did get to throw out the ceremonial first pitch at a game at Yankee Stadium on September 6, 2016 (I believe I caught the corner of the plate for a strike).*

Comment: Is a pitcher speaking?

Comment: Your question needs more context. Please edit. A look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) might help.

Comment: Yes the pitcher speaks

Comment: A related idiom is to "paint the corners" of the strike zone.

Answer (score 2):

To get a strike in baseball, the pitcher must either throw the ball over the plate, or have the batter swing at a pitch. The speaker in your example is saying that they barely made it over just the corner of the plate, which still counts as a strike. "Caught" in this context is similar in definition to saying "I woke up late and barely caught the train."